# Log-out everywhere and Auto-login both not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, logout, google-openid, auto-login

I am running Google Chrome on Linux, and am using my Google Account to authenticate with SE sites.

1. In the past, auto-login has always worked. (seeing the banner+refresh and I was logged in).
2. I recently reinstalled Chrome and reset all settings. This was a few days ago and with all cookies gone, I was logged-out everywhere.
3. **Since then, auto-login has not been working**. I have logged in to multiple SE sites using my Google credentials, but auto-login never worked. Even after rebooting, etc.
4. Thinking it might be some strange bug, I tried logging out as described here: [Log out of all Stack Exchange sites with linked account simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/log-out-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-with-linked-account-simultaneously)
5. The [logout page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) indeed logged me out, but just from the SO site. The question linked above would suggest that I should be logged out everywhere on SE. But e.g. I'm still logged in here on Meta (and all other sites). **So logout-everywhere is not working either**.

Suggestions on how to restore the intended behaviour are welcome.

**EDIT**: Auto-login works again!

Comment: To the auto-login part: [Why is global auth disabled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238220)

Answer (score 5):

Some idiot pushed a change with an extra `!` causing global authentication to be disabled when we're read-write instead of read-only. We're still trying to figure what imbecile would do such a thing.

Comment: Auto-login works again. The logout everywhere feature is still broken though. Any ideas?