# "Welcome back, $USER. You've been logged in." should appear whenever I visit a question, not only on the question list

Tags: bug, login

I've seen this couple times already. I visit a site using a link from Google or Stack Exchange itself, I'm not logged in, and yet the "Welcome back, Braiam. You've been logged in." doesn't appear until I go to the main/question page. This doesn't seems like the desirable behavior (in fact I remember that *was* the behavior). Can we fix, PLOX?

Comment: -1 for PHP.  SO is coded in glorious C#.

Comment: @Won't actually is shell script...

Comment: Because SO is written in shell script?  Admit it, PHP dev.  Admit to your crimes.

Comment: @Won't [you sure?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eKo1n.png)

Comment: Hah!  A clever ruse!  But I see through it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this behavior no longer exists after the old site-specific authentication scheme ("global auth") was removed and replaced with network-wide universal login.

Answer (score 2):

It normally does:

> [image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure why that doesn't happen for you, but it definitely sounds like a bug.  Some things you could check to help us (and the SE staff) diagnose it would be:

- Which browser(s) does this happen on?
- Does it still happen even if you disable all browser extensions?
- Are there any relevant error messages logged to your browser's [developer console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when you open a question page where the notice *should* appear?
- Just to be sure, does the HTML source for such pages include anything like [`"globalAuthDisabled": true`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238220/why-is-global-auth-disabled)?