# Thank you, Shog9

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks, community-managers

[@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), a longtime Community Manager here at Stack Exchange, [has just tweeted](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1216752358933184512) that he is no longer working at Stack Overflow:

> **@shog9**: Well... I suddenly find myself in need of work.
>   If anyone's hiring: C++, JavaScript, C#, SQL + solid background in social software, community-driven development.

In light of this, I would like to take the opportunity to say thank you.

**Thank you, Shog.** You've been an integral part of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network since the very beginning. You were among the most helpful people on the network, especially for moderators.
Losing your sense of humor, unique sense of communication, and point of view is a deep blow to SE.

**Thank you for everything you've done for SE and the community.** Good luck in whatever you choose to do next. **salutes**

Comment: Not enough sad emojis for this :(

Comment: I'm simply reeling. What the heck is going on?

Comment: Also destaffed: [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)

Comment: One of the most professional, well-spoken staff members... Gone. Such a loss.

Comment: @JohnDvorak It looks like Robert was part of the commnuity team based on his profile, which lists him as the Director of New Community Development, so maybe SO is reorganizing/downsizing the community team.

Comment: Does anyone have a list of community team members? Might be worth checking their profiles to see what their status is.

Comment: @DavisBroda There is a list [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341) but it's understandably outdated at the moment.

Comment: @DavisBroda - Catija, animuson, Juan M, JNat, Grace Note, Tim Post, Jon Ericson, hairboat, Cesar M, and Nicolas Chabanovsky all still had their diamonds last I checked.

Comment: Darn it, Shog, I thought you said you wouldn't die on that hill. What happened? You said something, right?

Comment: Is it too soon to say "We're sorry to see you go"? Bravo SE, Bravo.

Comment: It looks like Grace Note and animuson are no longer on the CM team list :(

Comment: @rossipedia We haven't been CMs for almost a year. We're on a different team now.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks SE just doesn't care about community's opinion anymore? Obviously, this is an internal matter; but after all we've been through, no sane company would let one of few employees who is in good terms with the community go. I suppose they think they already have enough material to stay alive without our contribution.

Comment: This is tragic to me even though I am not going to be much active. Thanks a lot shog for everything you gave to this community

Comment: [Super Shocked Look On Face]

Comment: This hits me far harder than any moderator resignation. Up until now, I could convince myself that things could get better, since at least one intelligent and trustworthy person still worked for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I guess that's it then. Journey over. Time to log out for the first time in nearly 10 years.

Comment: Half of meta consists of Shog contributions. At least sometimes it feels like this. His contribution to what StackOverflow made great is unmeasurable. Thanks Shog, for everything.

Comment: What is going on at StackExchange that all these talented people are voluntarily leaving or being forced to leave?

Comment: We truly are in the darkest timeline. :c I'm not very active on meta, but of all staff members I've seen here, Shog seemed to be one of the most reasonable.

Comment: Shog, what are you guilty of? Being intelligent? Being reasonable? Being patient? Willing to listen, to talk, to discuss, to explain? Putting your heart and soul into everything you do?

Comment: I clicked this thinking this would be a nice post from one of the CMs thanking Shog for many years of service and that he announced he was moving on. I am.... disappointing to say the least.

Comment: I'm not even sure there _was_ such a thing as "Community Manager" before Shog. I may have my history a little mixed up, but if he's not the original, he's at least the exemplar.

Comment: And there I thought it would be a perfectly normal Monday. Anyway, what is the plan now? Take the content and the users, create a charitable foundation, donate money and hire Shog?

Comment: `Well... I suddenly find myself in need of work.` Can someone translate this to non-coorporate-english? Does it mean he was fired?

Comment: @problemofficer - Yes.

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica Come now, David. You're not disappointing! We still believe in you.

Comment: Shocked but not shocked. Shog9 has always been the pinnacle of professionalism and community spirit, and SO has been moving further and further away from those things. Saddened to see you leave, but I know you will be successful wherever you end up next. The impact Shog9 has had on this community should not be underestimated.

Comment: Thank you for everything. I don't think you will have trouble finding a job where you are appreciated for the great work you do. You've got thousands of people rooting for you.

Comment: Want to downvote because I don’t want it to be true...

Comment: I'm kind of lost did Shog and Robert get fired or did they quit?  I'm not understanding this?

Comment: @JonH They apparently got fired. For what reason is presently unclear, although the vaguely threatening message about "aligning the company" they posted after that leaves little room for a charitable interpretation.

Comment: Stack Exchange is falling apart in front of us

Comment: Well, fired or abruptly laid off.  I would guess the latter; SE is restructuring, cutting costs, changing targets.  There's talk here about Meta going away, but I would actually bet that most of Stack Exchange is going away, in a 'profitability purge'.  This is about the time that the new CEO's initiatives start getting put into place.  Just a hunch.

Comment: I find it baffling how people are still unable to recognize there's an agenda at play here. Particularly since The Purge appears to be in full swing now.

Comment: Seems well-spoken to me, @Möoz. Very clear and concise. Quite elegant by my standards. It helps to understand that moderators don't arrive at decisions like that on a whim, so seeing a message like that makes it very clear that there was an eternity of nonsense that led up to the decision. At that point, one really appreciates someone like Shog who knows where to draw the line, who doesn't waste his time with things that aren't worth the time. The site, and all of us, were better off for it. The plain-spoken honesty was a nice refreshing treat, too.

Comment: @Möoz Page not found.

Comment: @John Dvorak: Re *"Destaffed"*? Euphemism joke? Or is it really used?

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica Yeah they're too busy writing more ads for Teams on the blog, to thank Shog for his enduring service over many years. That's really a kick in the teeth. What a horrible company.

Comment: It is extremely disappointing that this didn't warrant an official announcement. Just further driving me away from this place.

Comment: Apparently, there is a [gofundme page for shog9](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow) set up by [George Stocker as announced on twitter](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217437011876945920).

Comment: This is incredibly sad; but best of luck to shog in his future endeavors.

Comment: Is Stack Exchange pushing people out?

Comment: My experience with Shog was always positive. He worked tirelessly for the improvement and benefit of the site. The smallest (and often annoying I'm sure) requests for help that required dev access to bridge the many gaps between mod tooling vs useful functionality were always handled calmly and promptly. Thank you for Making Stackoverflow Great.

Comment: This really breaks my heart.

Comment: Statistical data will seem less fun without Shog9 keeping their Eye on things ..

Answer (score 2090, accepted):

No... Thank *you*.

My head's still spinning; nothing lasts forever, but... Sometimes we fool ourselves thinking it might. But one thing I know: I'm deeply, sincerely touched by this thread.

I've always considered y'all - the people who make up Stack Overflow - to be my boss, my leader in this job.

And... shit... y'all have been the best boss I've ever been privileged to work for. Quick with both praise and constructive criticism, never too busy to talk, knowledgeable on a seemingly infinite variety of topics but never too good to educate.

I've learned a lot from you over the years. Came into this as green as could be, but y'all were patient and understanding.

You've taught me what true collaboration is.

Thank you for allowing me to serve these past 9 years. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Accepted in less than a minute, +25 under two. Here is the community -- dare I say *your* community? -- at work.

Comment: As I told one of the first moderators who resigned some time back: the honor is with you, for *serving* us. And I hope we can make this one of the **top voted** MSE posts of all times!

Comment: I'm not crying, I'm not crying (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: Thank you for everything you've done for all of us here! You've made this a better place with all of your talent and hard work. It's a great loss to us that you're moving on, but you'll make wherever you go next a that much better place than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Without you, nothing will ever be the same. Thank you!

Comment: Over the years we often disagreed, sometimes argued, got very frustrated with each other -- but it happened because we both *cared deeply*, and I felt we had productive discussions (and arguments sometimes).  Diversity means encountering perspectives other than your own and I think that benefited us both.  I learned from you and I hope we continue to interact.

Comment: Best of luck on what comes next for you! It was a pleasure to work with you. And occasionally I got a word in. ;)

Comment: There are too many things I would need to thank you for but allow me to highlight one aspect: Your guidance and assistance in relation to [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) helped me and the rest of the team enormously over the years to establish where we are today. I'm going to miss that "eye". Take care ... :(

Comment: You always operated on a different level than the rest of us. When even moderators were losing sight of the forest for the trees, you'd identify the *real* problem behind the symptoms we were so focused on. Not only that, you'd be able to explain it in a way that made it seem obvious all along. I don't know what we'll do without that kind of perspective. To say you'll be missed is a ridiculous understatement.

Comment: For the first time I think I should stop moderating SO main. I've kept going all this time for the sake of the community, but losing you is the milestone from which I don't believe there's turning back. So sad to lose you and what you stood for. The company has no idea what they've lost.

Comment: You've been a source of inspiration for many. I cannot remember how many times I have jumped from one to another of your posts just to enjoy your ability to communicate, teach, and doubt at the same time. And then going and making things happen by working hard. I will very much miss you and hope the best in your future works. All the best!

Comment: You and I did not get along, but I personally know that it was me not getting along with SE, and you just happened to be the mediator. I very honestly wish you the best, and lots of success working for a much better company.

Comment: it has been a true pleasure working with you, my friend - I hope we can do so again in the future <3

Comment: I wish I could turn back time and tell you and others more often how great of a job you are doing.  It probably wouldn't change the outcome, but I want you to know that you have my respect.

Comment: And here I was thinking that this was a less routine kind of day at work.  Should've known something was off.  Holy crap, this is unfortunate news.  I thank you for your service here and, yeah, I don't really think a simple comment is gonna convey how much you were appreciated by me here.

Comment: We were lucky to have you and now that you are gone, nothing will be the same here. It was a pleasure working around you and with you. Thank you

Comment: This post reminds me of [this scene in *To Kill a Mockingbird*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7CX_5D6y6E). An upvote is a poor substitute, when we should be standing.

Comment: I'm supposed to be on strike from SE, but this is too big to leave alone. I'm sorry this happened. You've done your job extremely well. We haven't talked a lot, but there's just something about your way of communicating that's completely spot-on in so many cases. I'm not entirely sure how to sensibly describe it. I've said this elsewhere, but if SE had more employees even just a little bit like you, it would be a significantly better place. Thank you for all you've done.

Comment: From my days as a noob to becoming a somewhat established member of SO, you have always been a great example of knowledge and moderation wisdom. Thank you so much for all your work for the community. I will miss you.

Comment: Thanks for being a wonderful colleague and human.

Comment: Thanks Shog. From the get-go, you have thrown down for this community and we will be worse off without you. You've been wise, perceptive, pragmatic, selfless and always knew how to poke fun at us and yourself. I'd still [chuck a vote your way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35663/242) ; )

Comment: Damn Shog. I don't think you could possibly know how much you have taught me over the years or how much I have come to respect you. I have always appreciated your calm voice of reason. Even when we've disagreed, you have always had good arguments to back your position. I wish we'd had a chance to have a drink and actually meet face to face. If ever we happen to be in the same area, I hope we'll get to do so. I wish you all the best, and go with the knowledge that you have actually made a difference. That's more than most people can say.

Comment: You were never green. Verbose, maybe :-). You've taught so many of us how to interact with other humans on the internetz; the impact you've had has been immesurable. I never comment on these questions or answers, but this is such a shock...

Comment: I really thought you were part of the furniture. I should know better than that. It's been a privilege to work with you (and yes I do think the relationship between CM's and moderators is work).

Comment: et tu Shog? I wish you the very best for the future, including finding an even better job double-quick (or as quick as *you* want to — I think you deserve a nice long holiday myself)

Comment: Don't be a stranger.

Comment: I'll have to second what everyone else said. I learned much about community organization and moderation from you; Stack Exchange will be missing not only a valuable employee but a longtime leader. Good luck with whatever comes next!

Comment: BTW Your meta profile still lists your @stackoverflow.com e-mail address, etc.

Comment: Just want to say I'm going to miss your dedication to improving the **quality** of content here, not just the quantity.  I do think you really helped all of us to ask better questions, and respond with better answers.  Thanks for all the ways you've helped us.

Comment: WTH is my only possible reaction.  You’ll be missed 

Comment: I cannot think of a single interaction I had with you that was not positive (this includes times I didn't, sometimes still don't, agree with you). In fact, the last positive interaction I remember having on SE (in Tavern in fact) was reminiscing with you about the good old days of coding when Java 2E was the new thing and all the ways we used to have to look for answers before SE. In just being yourself, you reminded me of all the reasons I loved SO when I first found it. You gave me hope in what SE could still be...and this? I am beyond shocked. I can only say good luck and thank you.

Comment: Out ... of ... words. A million thanks won't suffice for all you've done for the community.

Comment: I am surprised and devastated! I always saw you as one of the major pillars of the CM team, putting together statistics, elections, etc! I was "warned" in chat to not use your name or otherwise you'd be summoned with all your power and who would know what might happen then ;) I am very, very sad to see you go; you were on the "good" team for me :/

Comment: Stack Overflow without Shog9 is not Stack Overflow anymore :(

Comment: Sad to see you go, you've been a great help, also for us small science communities.

Comment: Our encounters were few, and I think I was not as polite as I could have been. I'll see this as my last chance to apologize for any rude words I may have spoken in anger. I hope wherever you go, you will find a great environment.

Comment: Now I know I don't really want to be part of this "institution". The community, yes. But SE can cease to exist and I won't shed a tear or heave a sigh. It was a pleasure to be here during your tenure. I'm sure you'll be an asset whereever you end up. Maybe on Microsoft's new Q&A site?

Comment: Thank you for all your work with the communities! I've mostly met you on Server Fault, and we've not always agreed, but I've always seen you as a person trying to make a good platform for all participants. You will be missed.

Comment: I did not expect that.  Maybe there is time to move to next SO and leave SO to rot.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and effort in helping me become a better Mod and being there when needed. You will be sorely missed by this person, if not everyone here at SE. Sorry to see you go, no doubt. With your skill set I have no doubt you'll land solidly on your feet. Here's to hoping that landing happens quickly and in a secure place. Good luck, My Friend.

Comment: It's the end of an era... *thank you* for all your work!  You truly were (and always will be) one of the great ones.  As Lysander from Diablo II once told me, "I'm sorry things didn't turn out as you had hoped. Go and remember us fondly. You know, you bothered me far less than most."

Comment: You seemed to be one of the few calm, level-headed people at SE who was *really* engaged to fight the slings and arrows of disappointment that SE has caused for the community. But maybe it's not the worst thing that could happen. Why? Well, people will hate me for posting this link (because it features a speaker who has caused some \*ehrm\* controversy), but I think *what* he says fits perfectly here: https://youtu.be/SKzpj0Ev8Xs?t=7948

Comment: Thanks for holding out as long as you did, Shog. You will be missed.

Comment: I'm at a loss for words. All I can think of to say is **thank you so much**. You were so good at all aspects of your job -- from the technical to the social -- and you were such a helpful resource for advising moderators like me. This is a critical loss for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks for all the fish.

Comment: Shog9 - You've consistently been the most eloquent voice coming from Stack Overflow, and I was repeatably impressed with your communication skills and your ability to frame subjects and sweep discussions and lead the community behind you. Good luck.

Comment: While I can't say I know you well, you've repeatedly come across as one of the sole voices of reason on SE's side during the recent troubles.  Seems it would take a blind and deaf manager not to recognize the value of that in the current climate, but then again....  Well, in any event, I wish you all the best.  It's a rare talent, these days, that sort of thing.

Comment: You did great work, Shog! I enjoyed reading your postings, seeing the profound thinking behind your decisions. Thanks for all your hard work, and all the best!

Comment: Best of luck wherever you go and whatever you do. You gave me perspective when I needed the most. The hole you leave behind is huge.

Comment: Was going to keep my mouth shut originally since my only interaction I remember with Shog9 was very negative, perceived by me to be an abuse of power when he was deleting comments linking to a meta post about a question he was taking action against and he got angry when I added a "This question being discussed on meta here" comment back in (I didn't realize he was staff, though that shouldn't have mattered). I decided to comment anyway once I read Shog's answer here, only because of Shog9's statement here that he viewed us as his boss: he argued exactly the opposite in our discussion back then

Comment: … however, because of all the statements I'm reading here, I'm willing to accept that maybe the actions that day were not characteristic of Shog's usual behavior. I've always remembered that day as one of my worst SE experiences, but since Shog is apparently such a great person as seen by so many witnesses here I'll let it go. Maybe he was just having a terrible day that time.

Comment: @Loduwijk I mean...you should have let that go a long time ago, that *was* part of Shog's roles here, to manage the community (the ups and downs). And he did that remarkably well, making difficult decisions when needed (even if I disagreed with him sometimes) but always being fair and transparent about the reasons for them

Comment: Always respected those times you showed up over at GameDev for problems we had.

Comment: People are saying a lot of nice things, as they do in these situations @lodu - but I'm not perfect, or even good; I made a lot of mistakes and had plenty of off-days. I don't recall the exchange you reference and can no longer look such things up... But I can apologize all the same: regardless of my intent, giving you your worst day on SO is clearly a failure on my part.

Comment: It's better to be out now than to wait until the whole damn thing goes down in smoke. I'm only still here to witness SE's fall.

Comment: Dude :( Still going to have to have that beer sometime though! Don't think you're off the hook just because you're off the clock :P

Comment: @Shog9 _“But I can apologize all the same: regardless of my intent, giving you your worst day on SO is clearly a failure on my part.”_ — this is simply moving. This is the level of empathy and humanity that Stack Exchange Inc. will forever lack without you.

Comment: Speaking of beers, @Shog9 you do owe me a cider.

Comment: @Loduwijk dude, Shog9 just got fired from his job of 9 years. This is a prime time to practice "if you don't have something nice to say, then don't say anything at all". The fact that he took the time to respond politely to you says everything you need to know about him.

Comment: [O Captain! My Captain!](https://youtu.be/BF9ofkIXFts?t=83)

Comment: @StrongBad As I said, I originally wasn't, but reading all this made me literally think "Ack, I feel like I'm going to puke." I wouldn't have said anything if it were some minor abuse; it was a big blowup, literally ruined my day and then some and caused me a sleepless night. I am not exaggerating, not one bit. It was exactly the opposite of the type of comment he responded with above. Still would have said nothing if he hadn't made the statements in his answer here, it made me feel sick. Please don't judge me. I'm not judging; just needed to get it off my chest then let it go. As I ...

Comment: … said, maybe it was a fluke. None of us are perfect. I have plenty of my own glaring problems. He must have not been what I thought, so I'm letting go and moving on because of what I'm seeing here, just as I hope others do for me. But I felt I needed to say _something_. All I can do is what I believe to be the right thing, and my comment above was not out of any malice so at least there's that. Maybe it was the wrong thing to do, maybe not, I'm not sure.

Comment: And on second thought, I would not want to have a mistake I made taint my legacy, no matter how dire the mistake, and I try to live by "do unto others as you would have them do unto you", so I still might delete my comments here.

Comment: @Loduwijk If you want to share your experiences, I recommend posting an answer, rather than leaving a dozen comments. These are hard to read and make the entire discussion difficult to follow.

Comment: @CodyGray Though I thought at the moment that I should say something, I certainly did not want to bring the attention to it that an answer would attract. I'm not trying to cause problems, and I don't want to ruin this thread. I felt at the moment that I should say something, but it should be said with a small sign, not a large one (Or maybe none at all). And this discussion branching off about my original comments is only making it worse, so this is the last I'll reply about it.

Comment: I think it's fine that @Lodu shared his experience here. Lest we forget: even Richard Nixon collected accolades upon his death... It is all too tempting to venerate in situations like this, while overlooking the faults. I've been here a long time, written hundreds of thousands of words... And many of those words were far more cutting than they strictly needed to be. Those are facts, and I must live with them. A person who cannot accept their faults or acknowledge the hurt that they've caused is worthless.

Comment: Travis, Meg, and anyone else with a thirst for a drink and company... If ever you happen through my neck of Colorado, stop in and be served.

Comment: I shall never forget to look up...to you. Thank you for all the work, the insights  and the fun.

Comment: I have tried to write words as an answer to express my appreciation for our friendship over the years @Shog9 and have failed. I can only think to write: thank you. I am a much better person from the _years_ we got to know each other. :'(

Comment: "y'all have been the best boss I've ever been privileged to work for" and you've been one of the best employees SO ever had the privilege of employing. I'd love to refer you for a job at my company, if you're interested. Let me know. If not, and even otherwise, best of luck in all of your future endeavors.

Comment: [The start interview](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/15494022-stack-exchange-sta.mp3)(?) (second podcast series, episode 5, 2011-05-18). The interview starts at 11 min 05 secs.

Comment: I will ***DEFINITELY*** miss you 

Comment: 9 years, eh? I'd wondered about the numeral in "Shog9" ... should'a made it Shog99 instead. Thank you for building the community during your time at SE. You've left some big shoes to be filled.

Comment: This is noe the 5th highest scoring answer on MSE, and still rapidly climbing the ranks. Lets honour Shog9 by making it the highest scored answer ever.

Comment: There is a [gofundme page for shog9](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow) set up by [George Stocker as announced on twitter](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217437011876945920).

Comment: Thanks for everything, Shog9. Best of luck with your future endeavours, wherever they may take you. :)

Comment: Shog, you deserve to make that 9 a 10.

Comment: We will miss you.

Comment: If you're still looking for work, I think there's a position where I am that would be a good fit for you. You still have my email address?

Comment: I don't, @kit - but you can find mine on my website

Comment: @Shog9 - I remember Richard Nixon. I grew up watching Richard Nixon on television. And Shog, you are no Richard Nixon.

Comment: The good ones always leave to soon. Good luck.

Comment: It's so sad that so many moderators are leaving including Robert, and Madara. Oh no, not you!

Comment: @Shog9 I'm sorry to hear about this. Thank you for being so involved with the community especially lately, and being present and all that you've done with the site. I hope things work out well in terms of your next career chapter.

Comment: [This is now officially the highest-voted answer on Meta SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa)

Comment: Oh, no!  You were my favorite moderator!

Comment: Thanks for everything Shog, learnt so much from you. Best of luck for your future.

Comment: I've never thought about deserting from SE/SO until today when I learned about Shog9's leave (and some further bad news from recent days). What the F* is going on here? Was Stack(.+) sold and were some liquidators hired to scrap whatever value can be scrapped? Because that's what I'd think if I saw such things happening in any other less-community-based company.

Comment: «nothing lasts forever»... if nothing lasts forever, that message also doesn't last forever which means there's at least something that lasts forever.

Comment: @Loduwijk I had a similar experience and still remember it.

Comment: @Shog9 - I didn't know you live in Colorado. I'm in Denver. Let's get a drink. You know, my only experience with you as a moderator is when you quite unexpectedly blew up the Mos Eisley chatroom in Science Fiction/Fantasy. It was so devastating because we had a community. An imperfect one, yes. But a caring community nevertheless. However, I have read enough of your moderation comments over the years to know that you are not cruel or power hungry, and that you are a smart and competent mod. But getting our chat destroyed really hurt. We were working hard on improving our vibe. Take care.

Comment: Just an FYI that I wrote the above comment and don't know why it signed my comment as "A Slytherin". Weird! - Slytherincess

Comment: That was a painful time, @aSlytherin - I've reflected on it a lot over the years, and used the lessons to inform quite a bit of guidance on proactive intervention as well as a design for improved chat tooling that ... May eventually see the light of day. Once this social distancing stuff relaxes a bit and the bars reopen, I'd love to have a drink & discuss! You can find my email on my website. (P.S. I recognized you anyway )

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes, that was a hard time. But, you know, now I truly hope that the Mos Eisley experience can become useful as an example of challenging moments in moderation, and that perhaps current moderators can learn what to, or not to, do to work with chatrooms that have good people in them, but are still producing problematic content. With Mos Eisley, mistakes were made on both sides. But perhaps by studying what happened, moderators could learn more effective techniques in dealing with problem chatrooms. Some good could come from this :) Could I get your website's URL? - Slytherincess

Comment: Sure, @aSlytherin - https://www.shog9.com

Comment: Shog9, I know we haven't always seen eye to eye on a few matters, but you have been, undeniably, one of the most valuable assets on this this network.  I miss you; tons of people miss you.  You are a legend here.  Thanks for your service!!

Comment: This answer is just eight up-arrow clicks away from becoming the first 2000+ answer on all of Meta.  Congrats, Shog!

Comment: I'm lucky to witness now have witnessed a post at 2000 score exactly! I'll make my sighting more valuable by drawing legs on the snake.

Comment: To those who edit to remove the profanity:  In general, profanity should be removed from posts - e.g. in case of frustration or just because - but IMHO there are circumstances where the post should be left as it was originally written, in the author's own words.  In this case it's also pretty minor; plus, this post and thread signifies a lot.  Let's leave it as-is, unless Shog decides to approve that edit.

Answer (score 414):

Nowadays I'm always logged out of Stack Overflow so I'm not tempted to contribute, but I have logged in for this.

The world must be crazy. Shog9 is, in large part, the embodiment of what I find amazing, inspiring and humane in this community and in Stack Overflow in general. I can't believe any sane company would let him go away.

A few things I really want y'all to know about Shog.

- At times I've been at my worst and he was the only one able to see the good in me. He helped me very much before I was hired, when I was at Stack and even after.
- He has a very fine mind and working with him on anti vote cheat tools (to say one random thing we did) was really fun.
- I am very proud to be his friend. He is one of the people I wanted to work with when I got hired. He is one of the coworkers I was always eager to meet at the few Stack Overflow meetups we had. In particular, the Denver one was... to remember.

All in all, Stack Overflow is definitely worse off today but I can't wait to see who is the lucky company where he lands next. I might apply too :-D

Comment: "Shog works here" is automatically a huge selling point for any company IMO

Comment: @anonymous ever since they swore not to do it at Friday

Comment: Funny/sad background context: [Shog posted a farewell to Sklivvz a short time _ahead_ of Sklivvz leaving the company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291152/). Shog apparently deserved no such courtesy from current fellow employees. :(

Comment: '*Nowadays I'm always logged out of Stack Overflow so I'm not tempted to contribute, but I have logged in for this.*' - +1 simply for this line.

Comment: (An aside: Other people also said (in comments) that they are logging out (or not logged in). I'm still logged in all the time (even though I'm no longer contributing to SE), mainly because I think that this way, I'll generate less ad revenue. Malevolence? Maybe, call it what you like...)

Comment: @Marco13 use an adblocker, best of both worlds.

Comment: Hey, I'm a bit late on this reply, but... Thank you for these words. I don't deserve 'em, but I'm tickled to see 'em anyway - still miss working with ya, three years to the day later.

Comment: @Shog9 you totally deserve it

Answer (score 256):

Shog,

You taught me how to conduct myself in a written form. You taught me how to convey compassion and empathy. You taught me the value of a subtle take. You taught me how to help open minds to change without trying to bend them to my will.

You taught me how to moderate.

You taught me how to make mistakes gracefully, and how to own up to them to strangers. You taught me the importance of listening.

[Thank you](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow).

Comment: It's because of words like this that make this news shocking. Why get rid of your best community people when you (SE) very obviously have a critical community problem? None of their decisions have made any sense lately.

Comment: George, [your twitter thread](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1216771611484999682) on this is dead on the mark. Two highlights, if you don't mind me copying them here: _"That’s someone you write a blog post about announcing their departure. That’s someone who you give time to say goodbye. That’s someone who the severance starts at a minimum of 6 months. That’s someone who you create a new badge for to reflect their contributions."_ | _"...You may not value community moderation any more, @StackOverflow  but it says a lot about what you’ve become that you don’t respect the work they did."_

Comment: I have to agree with you, I'm disgusted to say the least by the way they've managed this. It's one thing to let shog go (which is already a pretty damn massive black mark against whoever decided it) but to do it like this is just shockingly bad and tone deaf. Shame on SE, and shame on every single manager who signed off on this.

Comment: Required reading: [The software community that Josh Heyer built](https://georgestocker.com/2020/01/14/the-software-community-that-josh-heyer-built/) Thanks, George.

Comment: I think you should highlight that gofundme campaign much more. The more people click that link, the better.

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing that might start getting deleted on sight, @Ghost. Hard to say. But it might be best at least to not _shout_ about it.

Comment: @jscs I am not sure about that part. It is one thing that SE Inc. doesnt want that you advertise a gofundme that is about taking them to court, compared to a gofundme that simply expresses the gratitude of the community towards a former employee. The gofundme doesnt waste time complaining, it simply explains that people might want to support a former friend of the community. I would very much hope that such a request doesnt get deleted ...

Comment: George, my first memory of you on the site was some argument over "cabal" vs "mafia" dragged over from the old TDWTF forums... Followed by seeing your noble efforts to improve a question result in someone trying to drag your name through the mud across the Internet! You've put an incredible amount into these sites over the years, been a steadfast supporter of both the community and the folks running the sites. Thank you for all of that, and for your kind words here.

Answer (score 215):

I know I won't be the first or last, but I just wanted to say thank you for everything, Shog.

I'm going to share one of my favorite memories, [too many Shogs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289395/242209)

> [image: Close bug]

May all those Shogs live on forever on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Shog-ception? Shog-ification? I don't even know what to label this.

Comment: Ah, Shog9.3... good times

Comment: There are too few Shogs now. I wish there could too many Shogs again.

Comment: Shouldn't the nine of them have different numbers?

Comment: Now that's what I call getting a good Shogging.

Comment: That was Shog27. But now it's Shog0 :(

Comment: Godspeed the crew of Shog17

Comment: Well have to add an [Agent entry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(The_Matrix)).

Comment: @Spevacus *Shog-puppets* :) . Thanks JAL for the chuckle your picture brought.

Comment: The eldritch community manager, yog-shogoth

Comment: Heh... Oh, I cringe a the thought of some future soul having to sanitize this data, cursing my name all the while... Thank *you*, JAL!

Answer (score 211):

Logging in for this. Shog, if you're reading this, I know what you're going through and I'm here for you man. You make up a big chunk of my fond memories of SO's early years. You have shown me true kindness and humility. I have great respect for you as a coworker and a friend. We bonded over food many times. I wish you the best in your future adventures.

Here's the last photo I took of you when we hang out in person, enjoy!

[image]

Comment: A wild codinghorror appears

Comment: Which one is Shog9 on the picture?

Comment: The person on the laptop screen is Jeff Atwood, @Cœur. Shog is not on the screen.

Comment: "Here's the last photo I took of you when we hang out in person, enjoy!" ...doesn't this imply Shog is the guy on the right?

Comment: The guy on the right looks awfully similar to the guy on the [Shoq's twitter picture](https://twitter.com/shog9). The way I understood this is that @Jin took the picture of Shoq holding a laptop while talking to Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Jin it has always been a pleasure - and as enjoyable as that farewell dinner for Bill was, what I'll always treasure the most was the second dinner you prepared afterwards (where we toasted Bill again). Thanks for the memories!

Answer (score 193):

There are folks I can't imagine this network be without. (and at this point, a few people I imagine we would be better off without). I think its pretty clear which one I consider Shog to be.

You will be missed - you had a gift for understanding the community and *people*. I've often said SE needed wisdom, grace and courage, and you're one of the folks who exemplifies all those qualities.

Of many baffling actions the company has done of late - I think this is one of the biggest.

We've lost too many good folks that actually knew what made this place great and made it home and yet, in the rush to build a shining city on the hill, other seem happy to pave it over.

Until recently my dream job was to be a CM here (Applied twice. They made excellent picks that were not me). There's a bunch of folks who... were, and still on the team who I consider friends. Shog? I looked up to. Even if I jokingly refered to him as a miscreant.

I've often talked of moderation as an idea of worth. I don't think Shog's could be questioned. He often made hard decisions, and occationally strange ones (that kinda worked out).

Ironically, when folks in the company talk of "building and growing" the community, we're short of someone who was at the heart of what made this community

(also folks, I know y'all fix my spelling mistakes, but for this once, leave it be. )

Comment: "*and at this point, a few people I imagine we would be better off without*" - Surely, about everybody here will agree with this.

Comment: I'm easily tired of coded references. I was surprised a moderator would think this thread was the place for it. I don't imagine *me* commenting further would change minds though, when Shog already spoke on this. [(1)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337689/194264) [(2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342041/why-is-se-gutting-the-cm-team/342274#342274).

Comment: Alas. No matter how disappointed I am, as a human being and a moderator - I need to practice what I preach. I will not lower myself to personal attacks. Shog expects that too from what he said on Twitter. This is a line I shall not cross. Not for SO's sake, but because that is what it takes to honour the spirit of the community we built

Comment: JG, you've been a pillar of your site forever, a protector and guide, someone I could always depend on. Your words mean a lot, and I thank you for them!

Answer (score 150):

This isn't a good news to hear at all. I'm definitely trying my best to hide my tears. Starting from when I was a new Stack Overflow moderator, till now, Shog has been a mentor and a role model to me and to others in the mod chat room. I would definitely miss Shog, and I am sure that he can never be replaced.

Shog used to work multiple extra hours just to make sure that things aren't going bad. He was one of the main people who were instrumental in getting a lot of the tag issues sorted out on Stack Overflow. Whenever we had any problem, or needed any data, Shog used to always be there and had become an integral part of our day to day lives. I definitely can't imagine how hard moderation would be without him.

Shog was also very helpful in setting up autoflagging in SOBotics, writing some of the autocomments for us. (He even [spared enough time for an interview!](https://blog.sobotics.org/2019/08/interview-with-shog9)).

Good luck Shog, I definitely know that you'd make your next employer proud.

Comment: Gonna miss your polite but persistent reminders that there be tags to put to right! I was privileged to be able to assist y'all in your work, and am gratified that you found use in my feedback!

Comment: and I'll definitely miss pinging you for getting the tags right. Those were happy times for sure!

Answer (score 131):

Shog, the opportunity to work with and learn from you was a highlight of my 2019. Really sad to hear this news. I can't even imagine how different my experience (and hence the community's, too) would have been without the influence and wisdom you generously and patiently shared daily. The next team you work with will be a lucky one. Take care.

Comment: Oh and hit me up if you wanna make that podcast

Comment: With you (Megan) & Shog9 gone, we lost 2 CMs that were very active in the mod chatroom. I'll miss that a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre but I couldn't manage to do the job of CM (especially not like Shog)! I was a product manager, but I do care a lot for the community ...

Comment: Meg, we worked together for far too short a time, but I loved every minute of it. I'll never forget your dedication, dropping in to question or clarify even when you were barely out of surgery and could hardly speak. As ill-advised as that was, it spoke volumes about your character - thanks for everything!

Comment: @Shog9 That's obsession! And ditto.

Answer (score 104):

Shog9,

It's hard to imagine what this community would have been like without your guidance over the years. There's probably not a single other person who has had the same influence that you've had. Thank you for spending the last decade writing literally *thousands* of answers to our questions on this site specifically, and across the entire network. Thank you for your patience and your candor, your wit and wisdom, and your eloquence and grace. Most of all, thank you for your friendship.

This community will miss you, but I'm sure you'll end up somewhere great (and they'll be lucky to have you, too). We all wish you the best of luck, and I hope to see you again.

Comment: Bill, the highlight of my time here was getting to meet you in person - *twice*! I learned a heck of a lot from the example you set, and never once regretted nominating you for mod-ship in that first "election". Thanks for the kind words and well-wishes!

Answer (score 100):

We may not always have seen eye to eye, but to me that's part and parcel of life.

To me, you are a ***huge*** part of what makes/made Stack Overflow (and its friends) what it is.

You will absolutely be missed.

I wish you all the best in your future endeavours!

Comment: I remember when you joined the site... You were "the other Tomalak" to me for a long, long time, even as your names changed. Yes, more'n a few times when we didn't get along, but I've always appreciated your persistence and willingness to engage and discuss. Thanks, and best of luck with your future C++ adventures!

Answer (score 75):

While I have not been a part of this site *nearly* as long as the many users who will take this news hard, I would like to contribute my two cents to the piggy bank of appreciation for Shog.

Your well-thought-out, often canonical posts on how to [properly utilize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/525551) the Stack Exchange network of sites have frequently guided me in my actions, and provided confidence that I was doing the right thing. Your [way-too-detailed reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390083/11384392) on experimental process changes scratched an itch I didn't know I had, as I marveled at how intricate even a narrow slice of this community was.

Your influence played a large factor in growing my interest in participating on these sites, and I know your legacy will continue to help and nurture those who come after. I wish you the best of luck on your future endeavors, and I don't think I speak wrongly when I say that we will all keep you in our thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Das - I'm happy that you found use of my scribblings here!

Answer (score 73):

Just a **huge, monumental** loss to our community as a whole.  The *ultimate* peacekeeper, and a person I could not ever win an argument against (a good thing usually in our interactions).

Clearly his value wasn't recognized.

Best of luck good sir, you're one of the good ones!!

Comment: Definitely not the "ultimate" peacekeeper - I've poured my share of gasoline on the flames too! But I did try now and then, when I remembered... Appreciate the well-wishes!

Answer (score 69):

Shog, I first heard of you many years ago when I started being active on SE. Anyone who came anywhere near meta would inevitably stumble upon one of your many thoughtful, insightful and just damned *fun* posts. You were instrumental in setting the tone of SE and defining the way we, the community, interacted with the company. You affected me long before we ever had any sort of contact.

When I became a mod, you were the ideal I was aspiring to. I wished that one day, this little mod would grow into a full blown Shog. I would watch you handle tricky issues and upset users with a wisdom and grace I couldn't come close to matching. Wisdom is a word that is overused, but you have consistently displayed it in [its most literal sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisdom):

> 1a: ability to discern inner qualities and relationships : INSIGHT
>
> b: good sense : JUDGMENT

If I had to choose one word to describe you, I would go for *wise*. And yes, I am well aware that you are way too young for that, one has no right to be called *wise* until hitting at least 80. Nevertheless, that is the word I would choose.

Thank you. Thank you for all the years of effort and thankless work you have put into this place. Thank you for always trying your best. Thank you for teaching me so much, either directly or simply by example. Thank you for your truly impressive ability to cut through the chaff and identify the real issue, whatever that may be.

As others have said, that you will be missed is an enormous understatement. It's not so much that you will be missed as that your absence, more than pretty much anyone else's, will fundamentally change this network and these communities.

Fare well, Shog, fare ye well.

Comment: Thanks terdon - I don't deserve any of these beautiful lies! It's been a pleasure working with you all these years, and I've learned a great deal from your thoughtful, well-considered, only *occasionally* crabby responses to a numerous and varied set of issues. Fare well as well

Comment: Ha! If I made only _occasionally_ crabby responses, I'm doing better than usual! :)

Answer (score 68):

Shog, I'm sorry to see you go. Really sorry as in being sad over this. Sad for myself for losing someone I respect and value, and sad for Stack Exchange that lost its best Community Manager and its best and most solid bridge with the community, bridge that survived many storms.

I was going to call you Josh to make it more personal, but [this chat message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6721472#6721472) from the past made me think twice and use the name you prefer, Shog.

To this day I sometimes recall the time [you called me "king"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5760686#5760686), and it makes me so happy each time!

> [image: king of pings]

You are the real king, Shog. Now without a crown, or a diamond, but you don't need those to rule. Show the world what you worth, and I wish you the best of luck wherever you go.

Shadow9

P.S.
[Your coffee](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8166422#8166422) is getting cold.

Comment: I will miss Shog's stats.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Now how will we know which of us is chattiest in the TL?

Comment: I'm not sure it will matter any nore

Comment: Why are you burning?

Comment: @Peter anger at SE, so it looked fitting. It express my internal feelings.

Comment: ShaWizDowArd, how will I ever keep track of your names now... Appreciate the words and well-wishes, hope to keep in touch!

Comment: @Sho well our names were always alike - remember [the song](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/721?m=4716581#4716581)? Thanks for dropping by, and yes I really wish you'll keep in touch with all the good folk around here! :)

Answer (score 68):

Dear Stack Overflow (the company),

Please take note. This is what good will from your community looks like. This is what you've given up in your new pursuits. This is what this community is capable of when you treat it with dignity. This is what we looked like before you decided we weren't "welcoming." This is what you've destroyed.

Even though most of my encounters with Shog were trying to argue him into a different position, I never distrusted his motives or efforts, even if I thought he or his method of defending a position was wrong. Despite my disagreements, I respected that he was ultimately doing his best to create an environment that fostered a healthy community of capable individuals to make Stack Overflow the best resource for information it could be. I know he cares about this site and the people who use it.

Respect is earned, not entitled. Whatever Shog's mistakes and failings might have been, he earned our respect. You have a great deal to learn from him, and that only makes his dismissal (regardless of whether you fired him for specific actions or simply laid him off) even more poignant.

Sincerely,

A frustrated, unwelcomed user

---

To Shog:

Thank you, Shog, for everything you've done for this community! This is Stack Overflow's loss. I know it's hurtful to be suddenly removed from a position where you could help the community you care so much about, but I am certain that you will be better off going than staying in this environment.

Comment: Thank *you*, jpmc26. This is what being part of a community is all about: learning to work with one another in order to build something great. We've butted heads plenty of times, but never for naught.

Comment: @Shog9 No, really. Thank you. I know I am often not the easiest person to listen to, so I am grateful to hear at least some good came of it. I am grateful that you looked past my failings and tried to find something worth listening to in what I said.

Answer (score 55):

There are the announcements which catch you off guard.  There are the ones that come out of left field.  There are the statements that seem to be spun out of thin air.

And then, there's ***this***.

Damn.

I honestly can't really string together besides a simple "thank you".  It was your guidance and involvement on Meta Stack Overflow that made me stick around for probably far longer than I should've, and I feel to some extent you've helped me look and think critically at questions, and not think that everything can be solved in the same way all the time.

With that, take care, and maybe our paths will cross again one day.

Comment: Thank *you*, Makoto. One of the highlights of my job here was the times when I'd jump in to answer a question... And find that someone else had already posted an excellent response, leaving me with nothing to do but click "upvote". When I saw your name on the homepage after "modified...", I could just take my hands off the keyboard.

Answer (score 52):

The incident which illustrated to me most what sort of person Shog was, was the [Min-Reprex: a less awkward name for MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve). The community overwhelmingly showed its opposition to it and Shog came back with [MCVExit redux: I don't need a milkshake to know when I've missed the mark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark).

He listened, engaged with the community, and returned with a solution which settled folk.

That's exactly what SE is missing and will be missed with Shog's departure.

Comment: We all make mistakes; we should all strive to learn from them. If I would not do so myself, how could I ever ask that of anyone else? Thank you, Script47!

Answer (score 51):

Unfortunately, I spent most of my "initial" years on this network just on Stack Overflow, looking into the purely technical stuff. I only came to understand the real (human) powers of this network lately. I asked about "moderation statistics" some days back, and shog9 ... just put that up. No fuzz, just the maximum amount of transparency that was possible to provide.

And now I am very sorry that more and more great people are leaving this place (MSE). Be it voluntarily, or unfortunately: not so voluntarily as it seems in this case.

I made it my policy: every time when I read a *new* post from model users, (or model community managers) to also read at least 2, 3 of their older postings.

And each time I learn something new and helpful about working together with other humans. And now, no new posts will come in from you.

Thus: I am very sad to see you go, and I am wondering how much can be taken away from this place before nothing of relevance is left.

And know this: in case you (and other *former* SE Inc. employees) will ever write up a book about your time at this place, I will happily order a paper copy of that! Meaning: don't be shy about blogging or tweeting about anything you got on your mind ...

The only sense I see in this: shog9 has the chance of finding a job in a *better* place now. Farewell.

Comment: Nothing unfortunate about it, GhostCat - it's folks like you who reminded me on the regular *why* I was here, who and what I was working for. It's been a pleasure, and... While I won't be posting moderation stats, maybe I'll get a chance to delve into some of that good sweet technical stuff again after all these years distracted. Thanks, and see ya 'round.

Answer (score 49):

Just, wow. Truly shocked.

Wherever you go, you will make them better by being around. And the loss here is... monumental.

You’ll be sorely missed.

Can we close shop now? Let’s all go to Quora, Reddit or whatever.

This place is looking more desolate with each minute.

Comment: When you're really looking for a place to go, look at my profile.

Comment: Quora? [Mostly](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio) [for](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-asteroid-16-Psyche-was-teleported-approximately-50-miles-off-the-coast-of-Southern-California/answer/Dave-Consiglio) [entertainment](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-you-instantaneously-moved-Uranus-so-that-it-was-touching-Earth), nothing else. They are also under pressure from investors, like Stack Exchange. They (Quora at least) are moving in the direction of Yahoo Answers (which ...

Comment: ... [is odd indeed](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed).

Comment: @Peter, frankly, I don't have much use or interest in either site. I was mostly signalling a "all is lost, abandon ship, look for any piece of flotsam to hold you".

Comment: Codidact _could_ be a new place... but it doesn't exist yet. I'm also concerned about some users choosing go there because they reject the CoC, and not because of the other failings SO Inc. But those fears might be unfounded, we'll need to see. Sadly, I have no knowledge C# nor much interest in getting into it. I wish they had chosen a something less microsofty.

Comment: Thanks yivi; it's always been folks like you who've made this whole thing work by learning and passing on what you learned. Appreciate it immensely!

Answer (score 48):

I've never been a community manager or even a moderator, just a user (primarily of SO initially, now others). But whenever I saw a post from Shog9, my feeling was always "The adults are here and paying attention. Everything will work out ok now."

Thank you for being the adult in the room. I'm afraid we'll miss your unfailingly thoughtful presence more in the future than we can ever imagine, even as we all proclaim to know how much you will be missed.

Comment: I wish I could have guaranteed that things would work out... But the best any of us can do is try to make the most of whatever situation we find ourselves in. Glad I was of some use - thank *you*, tmpearce!

Answer (score 47):

I've not yet made my mark upon Stack Exchange's network like many others have, but even I can see the impact that Shog has had.

There exists no better shining example of a community manager than Shog. Whether it's [replying to recent, niche bug reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338616/why-isnt-this-accepted-non-self-answer-pinned-on-top/341939#341939) or [wording a proposed (now completed) change to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), Shog has always been consistently professional and well spoken.

Despite the most obvious question of **Why?** burning deeply in my head... I have to focus on thanking Shog for his [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337127/a-letter-to-se-inc-please-protect-our-moderators/337228#337228), [nuanced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209779/stack-overflow-needz-moar-ads), and [sometimes humorous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590), contributions to the site.

I'm not confident that anyone could meaningfully replace the level of integrity, wit, and attitude that you put forward on a day to day basis.

Thank you, Shog, and good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Spevacus, for these memories - I'm touched that you remembered even something as long ago as that "ads" post! Ah, so much fumbling around trying to figure all this out... Glad to have you along!

Comment: Lurking for so long paid off! Thank you for making those memories, and I hope you take them right along with you into whatever your next adventure is. @Shog9

Answer (score 47):

Shog9, in every capacity which brought us into contact, you served your role well. Even when we disagreed¹, I *knew* you were listening and trying to understand — and that's a rare talent in today's world. I cannot imagine what shenanigans must be employed to justify letting you go as being "an investment in the community". As a [former moderator](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/30), I saw what you were doing for the community, and it was always a net gain.

Job. Well. Done.

<sub>¹ <sub>You were usually right.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you, Caleb. For this, and for all of the hard work you've done over the years, building, guiding, teaching, leading... The success of your communities owe more to your work than anything I've ever done or said; I'm happy I was able to occasionally be of some assistance.

Answer (score 44):

I ruminated some time on what to write, but didn't end up coming up with anything witty, or poetic, or worthy of the occasion. So I'll just leave with this:

I've always known you as a honest, dependable and compassionate person and community manager. We didn't always agree, but you were always fair and willing to take responsibility for your actions.

I cannot fathom what led SE to make this move, but it is to their eternal discredit. I hope your next employer will see your true value and treat you better.

Comment: Thank you, Magisch. It has been a pleasure to work with you for so long, to learn from one another and together accomplish much.

Answer (score 41):

Shog9 has been remarkable through his entire time here. Few people write as eloquently, retain as cool a head and decent a manner even when in a sea of acrimony, or can reason with the same clarity about the complex system of software and norms and people that makes up Stack Exchange. He is a loss to the company, and to us. And for him to be canned without warning, after a decade of often supererogatory service to the company, is an injustice - as was the similar canning of many of his peers.

Like a few others, I've thrown some money into [the fundraiser George Stocker has set up](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow) to ensure both that Shog lands on his feet and that the company cannot financially pressure him into signing away his right to speak about his time working for them. Shog was well-loved here, and so I hope that more people will do the same.

Comment: Thank you, Mark - for the support, and the kind words. See ya around...

Answer (score 37):

Shog, wishing you much luck with your future adventures. You were a fixture and an omnipresent voice of reason for the community.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, waffles. You should know: on my last day, I still had *hundreds* of Data Explorer tabs open. I lived in your work for the better part of a decade...

Answer (score 33):

Someone whom I was used to seeing on meta. Your contributions to this community don't have an end. There are countless things that you have taught me (maybe all of us) and you aren't even aware of that.

Who will get people shogged in the chatrooms now?

Some things that made shog, shog for me:

- Shog's quick replies on bugs and issues.
- The ability to sum up things in simple sentences that people fail to explain
- Solving disputes, writing amazing guidelines that formed the pillars of the main SO community

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks weegee - what a long, strange trip it has been.

Answer (score 33):

A clear eye and a ready wit. Unfailingly, unflinchingly forthright. Always an understated but decisive presence; a lens collecting and focussing the meta-knowledge as it accumulated; the Merlin to our Arthur.

What a tragedy. Anyone that would dismiss you like this doesn't deserve your skills, talent, and care. I can't imagine it's easy. But no one can take this away from you:

You were absolutely fundamental in building one of the wonders of this decade. The artifact and the people could not have made it this far without you. You should be deeply proud of your time here.

All my respect. I can only hope that I am privileged to cross paths with you again on these webs. Whatever project you put your hand to next will be fortunate to have it.

Comment: Thanks jscs - it's a big world but a surprisingly small community... I have confidence we'll meet again!

Answer (score 32):

I must say... I'm stunned and baffled. Shog9, you've been a mainstay of the community since well before I started participating. You'll definitely be missed.

Comment: Thanks EJoshuaS - appreciate it. It's been fun watching your path here, and I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 29):

Tons of people have said it already... But you will be missed, Shog9.

I know we didn't interact much since the relatively short time since I was elected as a mod on RPG.SE, but I learned a lot from you - whether about the Stack Exchange network, community management, or just... community interactions in general. It's always been interesting talking with you, and I appreciate your willingness to listen to people and hear them out.

You were always able to talk to people during difficult/complicated times, and (usually) get them to listen even when they didn't want to hear it. It is truly an impressive and fairly unique skill.

It's pretty obvious that you've brought a lot to this community, so I'm confident that you'll thrive wherever your life takes you next. I hope you keep making communities a better place, whether as a regular user here or wherever you work next.

Comment: P.S.: What will [Nog Shine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/357396/nog-shine) do now?

Comment: Gone Shine, of course.

Comment: No(g) Shine.

Comment: Thanks, V2Blast. We didn't get as much time to chat as I might've liked either, but I know well the role you stepped into and the work you put in getting to that point. RPG is an interesting site: lotta folks have sorta grown up there, even people who were technically adults already... It's been a privilege to watch y'all work through some really gnarly problems, *as a community* - I dare say I've learned more from that than I've ever taught. Hope to see ya around...

Comment: @Shog9: Thank you for the kind words. :)

Comment: @Shog9 That meant a lot to read. Thanks, Shog. I hope to see you around too.

Answer (score 27):

Shog9 was one of the hard working members of the Stack Exchange network with great communication skills, who made a lot of tough decisions and helped to hold the community together. It is indeed a sad thing to see that Shog9 is no longer a CM.

Comment: Appreciate it, Bill. Didn't always make the right decisions, but at least I made it look hard ;-)

Comment: Hey, nobody is perfect and your job wasn't easy. Two thumbs up from me :)

Answer (score 27):

Shog, in the hopes you read this.

My heart goes out to you.

Words do not do justice to the feelings that are swirling through my head. The questions this raises are another matter...

Many of the times we interacted together revolved around bad activity.
We have fought whole sock drawers together. We banished countless spammers (remember "I LOVE CORN SO MUCH").
You have been a rock that us mods could always trust and call for help. You have been the cool and clear head and the firm and direct one.
Truly this is a loss for the SE community. Shog you did so much. You had a reputation for saying the things we wish we could say. You were always "the one" we could ping, it seemed you were always here.
You touched so much of this network, so many of us.

Your absence is going to leave a big hole to fill.

However this really went down, we will never know - it sucks.

So Long, thanks for everything, and all the fish.

Farewell

Comment: Reminds me of something like "farewell winter bash"

Comment: In reality it's all just one spammer that loves food :P

Comment: Thank you, David. And... Let's be honest: corn *is* pretty great!

Answer (score 25):

A true anchor of sanity and constructiveness.

A couple of years down the road we'll suddenly see something incredible like Microsoft's Q&A finally starting to make sense, or a completely new but long awaited thing will come to life, and it's going to be no surprise it was the work of a certain someone.

Good luck on your future endeavours! And don't forget to take a break when needed.

Comment: An acquisition of Stack Exchange by Microsoft (like GitHub) is much more likely than an IPO.

Comment: Thank you, user1306322. I believe in this idea, this community, this great collective work. Its success or failure will come, not from people like me, but from those like you and the hard work done every day.

Answer (score 25):

I've come late to this, and I've just OK'd the "This question has more than thirty answers already: make sure you're adding something new" message.

That there are already thirty answers saying much the same thing speaks volumes.

What this says to me is that the company thinks it knows the cost of everything [although recent events may give the lie to that] and definitely does not know the value of anything.

A huge loss to every SE community, and the company -- in that order. A huge gain for whoever snaps Shog up, which I trust will happen quickly.

Shog, you've been kind to me in the past; you've been blunt; you've always had your head screwed on right, as we say here. I hope everything works out.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. It's been great - I hope sincerely that it will be again.

Answer (score 23):

Well. I guess that's that.

[image: Lights out for the last time]

Comment: It is both very funny and very sad at the same time.

Comment: Good night and good luck... ;-)

Answer (score 22):

Shog, big surprise to me!

Thanks for all you help to SO,

I always thought you were a fixed staff on SE, I always lookup to you as a very good staff doing all the jobs correct!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, U10; much appreciated!

Comment: @Shog9 Wow, great to see you still comenting here :-), thank you

Answer (score 22):

Farewell, Mr. Shog.

We're sorry to see you go.

**bursts into tears**

Comment: Boromir:
Our people... I would have followed you, my brother... my captain... my king. [dies]

Comment: It's not goodbye, just... see you later, Justin.

Answer (score 22):

@Shog -

Thank you Shog, you are a true idol of knowledge.

Shog was the heart of the community. Everyone here adores the guy, and not without good reason. He is an oracle, and wise beyond his years.

@SE -

WTF.

Honestly, I didn't really think it was possible for this much momentum to be interrupted over time, but this is truly a sobering act. Time for people to step down or get removed by the Board. You are lucky this thing isn't a public entity.

Comment: "_Everyone here adores the guy_". Which is probably why he had to go.

Comment: Thank you Travis - you're one of those folks I always look forward to encountering; you've always got something to say, and usually say it well.

Comment: @Shog9 - Hopefully I said it well here haha :) At the time I wrote this my heart was heavy and it was honestly difficult to write a meaningful farewell to you because the distress was real. Still not used to seeing your name without the diamond. Still planning on somehow getting to CO for a beer / whiskey / rum?, I swear, but seriously I haven't even taken a vacation in like 18 months.

Comment: Well, sounds like you need one then... Lemme know if you make it through!

Comment: Absolutely will!

Answer (score 22):

SE is strategically ridding themselves of people who are able and willing to deliver substantial critique to the decision makers.

They are dumbing themselves down: The remaining court of yeasayers will render SE incapable of necessary course corrections.

Comment: I suppose that there is more behind such moves than just changes to the company atmosphere. What about this: Cutting off those mods who have strong ties with the general public and have the most contributions to lose, then move everything to subscription-based, or some other legal form of commons-grabbing. No proof, just an attempt to find a rational motive.

Comment: @ccorn It does not make sense alienating a whole community before driving in a subscription-based model.

Comment: @ccorn "More to it": I agree. The firings are part of a larger strategy. One shift is obvious from the Monica Cellio scandal and also the CEO's recent message. It's the shift towards being "more inclusive and welcoming". Never mind that questions of newcomers (specifically on SO) are most of the times worse than useless: They take time away from users and mods to flag them as duplicates. (There are only so many questions a beginner can ask about C.) I also think that 10% questions by women likely reflect their share of the coder workforce, lamentably or not (coding is kindof dry, isn't it.)

Comment: While there's life, there's hope: no matter how bad, things may get better if only folks are willing to make them do so. Keep looking up, Peter!

Answer (score 19):

I am sorry that I had to write an answer this late. I was literally speechless when I saw this meta post and immediately logged out. Today I have logged in again to say Thank you.

*Thank you Shog for everything*.

I learnt a lot from you. You have been my idol on Stack Exchange.

You were one of the best writers I have ever seen.
I learnt how to talk when our mind is not calm.
I learnt how to talk less yet impact more.
I learnt how to moderate.

Nog Shine will not be the same without you.

Your impact will be there on me wherever I be. Thank you again!

You have truly been my [Good Friend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/357396)!

Comment: Thank you, Nog - I'll forgive you the fingerprints on my keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 18):

One of the most effective mentors I had known within the Stack Overflow/Meta and Stack Exchange network. It is sad to know that you are moving on. You will be missed.

No doubt @Shog's dedicated all around efforts in building and maintaining this network will be always remembered.

Hats off to you @Shog.

I wish you all the best for your future endeavors.

Comment: Thank you, DebanjanB - and know this: I don't work here, but this has always been my community, and so it remains; we're in this together.

Answer (score 18):

Reading through other answers, I must say that I envy those who know Shog. I am not much of a frequent contributor and didn't have interactions with him like others, but from what I have seen here and there, he *is* a great guy and working with him was an honor for whoever had the chance.

> I don't know you, but I'll miss you too!

And now that he <s>has decided</s> *is forced*  to leave the company, I see this as the Captain leaving the ship.

Comment: I don't think he "decided" to leave the company ... his tweet reads more as if he was fired.

Comment: @Randal'Thor well then, that's worse than I thought

Comment: More like thrown overboard than leaving and more like Steward and Machinist than Captain but otherwise spot on. :)

Comment: @Trilarion Luckily for Shog, he has a large inflatable life raft in his pocket, and there will be plenty of non-sinking ships passing by.

Comment: It is a pleasure to meet you, polfosol - regardless of circumstances.

Answer (score 18):

I never directly interacted with you, but, over the years, more than hundreds times I read your comments or answers. It helped me *a lot* to understand how things were supposed to be around here, and improve. Let me tell you this straight: you're the "*[the best damn cooler in the business](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y97As.jpg)*". OK, you certainly deserve more than an excerpt of one of the [Top 10 best worst movies of all time](http://www.robertbrumm.com/my-blog/44-reasons-why-road-house-is-the-best-worst-movie-of-all-time) :-)

But, still, you were one of the leaders of the pack when it came to use common sense, decency, and just needed to [Be Nice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTh5JzRziHE). You could chill out and keep a cool head when things heated up. <s>That's why people liked you, respected you, and listened to you</s>. That's why people like you, respect you, and listen to you.

As a non-native speaker, I had to search for "shog", and look for (what I thought were) hidden meanings, play-on-words... I found that, actually, it was a real noun/verb: [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shog) and [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shog). So, let me tell you that seeing you go, Shog, was a real shog. But I have no doubt that you can now, head held high, shog.

You helped build and keep this community afloat and warm for almost ***a decade***.  For this, thanks. May you find a calm and light blue sea and favourable winds. So long.

Comment: I always thought "Shog" referred to [Shoggoths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoggoth) from the Cthulhu mythos. IIRC his profile once read... "if I die in R'lyeh, at least I will die free".

Comment: @S.L. thanks! From Lovecraft, I know only the name, never read anything, I'll check this in the future. I guess you're closer than me on this one :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just warning you, Lovecraft was a master of horror stories... don't read him in the evening if you value your sleep!

Comment: Thank you for the well-wishes, OldPadawan. It has been a pleasure!

Answer (score 17):

Sad to see you go, but to be honest you are better off not working for a company that will fire its longest serving and hardest working employees, but defend to the hilt (with large cash payouts, no less) somebody who has broken the law whilst acting as a spokesperson for the company.

You will easily find somewhere else where your talents are appreciated. Good Luck!

Comment: You may well be right here, razethestray. I believe that there is a purpose to everything, and this too will lead somewhere necessary. Thank you for the confidence!

Answer (score 16):

> How did everything run so smoothly ?

[image: Shog9]
              [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=topactivity) at the controls.

Comment: A remarkable likeness, Rob :-)

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure whether we interacted directly, but I've always found your posts insightful, helpful, calm and incredibly professional. At a time when the community is up in arms more than not, that's surely an incredibly valuable skillset in its own right, so I'm stunned to see you've been let go.

That being said, I imagine you'll be snapped up rather quickly, and rightly so. You'll certainly be missed here, but I'm sure you'll reach new heights elsewhere. All the best on your new adventure.

Comment: Thank you, berry120 - I appreciate it, and whether heights or depths, I will always have a fondness for the good folks here.

Answer (score 9):

> "Whatsoever thy hand findeth to do, do it with thy might; for there is no work, nor device, nor knowledge, nor wisdom, in the grave, whither thou goest."

Thank you Shog9 for all you have been and done for this community.

Comment: Ecclesiastes 9:10 KJV

Comment: Thank you, blestab. "Wherefore I perceive that there is nothing better, than that a man should rejoice in his own works; for that is his portion: for who shall bring him to see what shall be after him?"