# Why isn't "Comments are not for extended discussion" the case on Meta?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, meta

Many times I have seen posts with a *long* list of comments under it, which is later replaced with one comment from a moderator:

> Comments are not for extended discussion. This conversation has been moved to chat.

I rarely see this happen on Meta sites, however. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a meta for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for)

Comment: @gnat `Error: Invalid duplicate source`

Comment: @gnat: That seems dubious, at best, like linking to a FAQ that isn't actually a [tag:faq] and isn't really about the topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meta sites are, inherently, discussion-based. Most questions use a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, and so there's maybe more interplay between the answers and the question then you might see on the main site. An important thing to take into account is that people are encouraged to voice their opinions on the question, as well as on answers. If you disagree with an answer, you should make your voice heard. Sometimes that leads to another answer, and sometimes that leads to a string of comments on both major and minor objections. So, right off the bat, that leads to more commend chains, period.

I think many mods - myself included - are a bit more reluctant to move these comments to chat. The question and answers are where discussion's supposed to be. I'd bet that in most cases, both in main and on meta, **moving comments to chat means that fewer people see them.** Clicking on a link and going to a chat room is an extra bit of effort that can dissuade users. The thing is, we really can't afford for that to happen on meta. Discussion is really important.

A final thing to consider is that the question/answer format isn't necessarily ideal for meta. **Stack Exchange is designed to reduce discussion; meta is supposed to encourage discussion within the same framework.** That poses a bit of a quandary. Meta should be more of a conversation, I think, than a formal question/answer thread in most cases. Comments mitigate the problems of rigidity, to some extent.

Anyway, this is just a moderator's opinion. I don't move comments to chat as much on metas, but I will from time to time, especially if two users have dragged comments into a somewhat irrelevant tangent<sup>1</sup>. It depends on the situation, but I'm overall less willing to move comments to chat on meta, and I think a decent amount of mods are of similar opinions.

---

<sup>1 Yes, that's happened, and yes, the two users got annoyed at me, but fortunately, it meant that people who had something relevant to say could say it.</sup>

Comment: To kick off this string of comments: I agree with you that relevant comments should stay where they were meant to be, not moved to chat. Personally I am not interested in chat, and I don't want to have to go somewhere else just to view comments which may, or may not, be worthwhile viewing. On the other hand, I think that long strings of comments on _serious_ posts should be "cleaned up" to just include those relevant to the post and helpful to other users.

Comment: It's an interesting admission that "moving comments to chat means that fewer people see them". Moving to chat is, has been, and continues to be a blight on this whole website. It's not QUITE like deleting all the comments but as you point out, it is nearly functionally equivalent. We need to replace chat with a better comment structure that better supports discussion without being a distraction, somehow.